# How do I disconnect from Connect-MsolService in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, entra-id

I have used below command to initiates a connection to Azure Active Directory in Power Shell.

```
   Connect-​Msol​Service
```

I have completed required operations, **But how do I disconnect?** Do I wait till session expiry?!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just close the window.

> As for your connection to Office 365, although there’s a Connect-MsolService cmdlet, there’s no corresponding Disconnect-MsolService cmdlet. So for Office 365, just close the Windows PowerShell window. *(Nevertheless, it’s still a good idea to do this last so you can properly disconnect from SharePoint Online, Skype for Business Online, Exchange Online, and the Security & Compliance Center.)*

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568015.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the following .NET method:
[Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService]::ClearUserSessionState()

Answer (score 1):

I do have the same question. I found solution by reffering below article, We can use the .Net ClearUserSessionState method. It worked perfectly.

cmd  : **[Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService]::ClearUserSessionState()**

Ref : **https://www.easy365manager.com/how-to-disconnect-from-msolservice/**

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be preferable to include the solution into the answer. Otherwise the answer gets useless when that link dies.